# Why get_the_post_thumbnail_url doesn't work with custom add size?

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

I've did this in the functions.php:

```
function wpse_setup_theme() {
   add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
   add_image_size( 'small-thumb', 800, 600, true );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_setup_theme' );
```

Than, if I do this:

```
<? the_post_thumbnail( 'small-thumb' ); ?>
```

it works correctly (taking the "cropped" image). But if I do this:

```
<? echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'small-thumb') ?>
```

It always choose the "default" (full) image. The same with:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'small-thumb' );
echo $image[0];
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: After adding this code did you regenerated thumbnails? As adding code won't regenerate thumbnail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding this code did you regenerated thumbnails? As adding code won't regenerate thumbnail. Please go a head and regenerate thumbnail it'll work

Comment: Is there a way to re-generate all images loaded in the past at once?

Comment: If you're using WordPress then yes you can install https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/ to regenerate all the old media images.